# How to get date from datetime from database in SQL

Tags: sql

This is my query to get the current date time. I don't know how to fetch only the date

```
SELECT SENT_TIME 
FROM APP_STATUS_WEBSERVICE 
WHERE APP_ID_EFAS = 809371
```

The result of this query:

[image]

Here it shows 22 October 2022, I just want to get the 22 only. How to do that?

I want display only date: `22`

Comment: Do you want the _day_, or the entire _date_?

Comment: In MySQL, use EXTRACT function. For example: select extract(month from '2022-11-16');

Comment: i just want to get date. ex : 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `DAY()` function:

```sql
SELECT DAY(SENT_TIME) AS SENT_TIME_DAY
FROM APP_STATUS_WEBSERVICE
WHERE APP_ID_EFAS = 809371;
```